# Restart row numbers with 0 if there is a activity date

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to populate month last login column using Active as the last login date?

[image: data table image]

Comment: Feels like you need some other date structure that collects login info and then calculate activity in last month?

Comment: @johnymachine this was an interview question. The interviewer mentioned this can be solved using window function.

Comment: In that case write fully detailed question is asked on interview, data table is not self explanatory I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cumulative max to get the most recent `active` date.  The trick is then the difference in months.  To get the most recent active date:

```
select t.*,
       max(active) over (partition by userid order by date) as most_recent_active          
from t;
```

Then for the months between:

```
select t.*,
       (extract(year from most_recent_active - date) * 12 + 
        extract(month from most_recent_active)
       ) as months_since
from (select t.*,
             max(active) over (partition by userid order by date) as most_recent_active          
      from t
     ) t;
```